# Extending max_execution_time on Laravel Forge (Digital Ocean)

Tags: php, nginx, php-ini, laravel-forge

I am looking to extend the max_execution_time on a Laravel development which is deployed to Digital Ocean via Laravel Forge. I have tried;

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

This did not work, I have also tried a .htaccess solution which didn't work and have updated the php.ini file within "/etc/php/7.0/php.ini" which hasn't had an effect, I am not sure if you need to restart the service after this but do not know how to do this?

The server is running Ubuntu 16.04.2 x64. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Have you done this within forge?

There is option for such updates under **PHP / Files** (bottom right corner). Forge should take care of any required restarts.

[image]

Comment: Legend! Thank you!

Comment: THANKYOU my god ive been so frustrate that my client cannot give me sudo password and almost broke the server and this is way come from laravel forge

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: If you want this `max_execution_time` updated for a website then `FPM` if you want this for a crontab task then `CLI`

Answer (score 5):

In the newer version (2020) of Forge you find it within `PHP` > `PHP Version` > `Edit`

[image]